# How to place images side by side within a fixed width div

Tags: html, css, image

```
<div id="attachments">
            <div class="attachment">
                <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080 ?Text=Digital.com" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="attachment">
                <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="attachment">
                <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00/000000?Text=WebsiteBuilders.com" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="attachment">
                <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="attachment">
                <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/FFFFFF/?text=Green.com" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Want to place those image side by side. Here:
1. #attachments -> is max width 290px & height 100px (so there should be a horizontal scrollbar)

- don't want to use `float`

Comment: You can use `flex` for parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add display: flex to #attachments and display: inline-block to .attachment. You will also need overflow-x: scroll for the horizontal scroll bar.

```
#attachments {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 290px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.attachment {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/wheel58m/pen/mdeYazQ)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I figured it out after trying for 2 hours

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.attachment {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

For example: https://codepen.io/fraggley/pen/eYpabjd

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my requirement was the container is a fixed width, you'r solution doesn't work on that. `#attachments {width: 300px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, before seeing the answer I figured it out after 2 hours of try.
Later I changed markup a bit & did:

```css
#attachments {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px !important;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.2);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
 #attachments .attachment {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
 #attachments .attachment .cancel-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  color: #6c757d;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
 #attachments .attachment .cancel-icon:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 #attachments .attachment .item {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="attachments">
    <div class="attachment">
        <i class="material-icons cancel-icon">cancel</i>
        <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/0000FF/808080?Text=Digital.com" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="attachment">
        <i class="material-icons cancel-icon">cancel</i>
        <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="attachment">
        <i class="material-icons cancel-icon">cancel</i>
        <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00/000000?Text=WebsiteBuilders.com" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="attachment">
        <i class="material-icons cancel-icon">cancel</i>
        <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="attachment">
        <i class="material-icons cancel-icon">cancel</i>
        <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000/FFFFFF/?text=Green.com" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

This worked for me